# Having difficulty understanding this snippet of code

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, binary-search

I came across this snippet of code and I have some difficulty understanding what it does and how to use it.

```
int fstTrue(function<bool(int)> f, int lo, int hi) {
    hi ++; assert(lo <= hi); // assuming f is increasing
    while (lo < hi) { // find first index such that f is true 
        int mid = (lo+hi)/2; 
        f(mid) ? hi = mid : lo = mid+1; 
    } 
    return lo;
}
```

If anyone can tell me what this is doing aswell as how I would use the function/output the value( since I dont understand what parameters `function<bool(int)>` takes) that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: This should help: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: The line starting `f(mid) ?` is definitely non-idiomatic (and not style-recommended) C++ ...

Comment: `f` represents a callable object taking an `int` and returning a `bool`. It is assumed that this object produces a non-decreasing sequence, meaning that, for any `x < y`, it can't be that `f(x) == true` and `f(y) == false`. `fstTrue` then uses binary search to find the smallest value `x` in the range `[lo, hi]` for which `f(x) == true`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Im still confused... Is this binary search in an array or?

Comment: It's a binary search on a sequence `{f(lo), f(lo + 1), ... f(hi)}`

Comment: BTW `f` is what is commonly called a "predicate" - a function that determines if some property is true or not.  That's according to the second comment.  But the first comment is a bit confusing: You don't normally call a function (the predicate `f`) returning booleans as "increasing"?

Comment: It's a binary search on a range containing integers which is assumed to be partitioned: On input to this function, all those integers for which the predicate `f` is false are at lower indices than those integers for which the predicate `f` is true.  Then it is trying to find the partition point: the index at which `f` changes from false to true.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh so for example if the number we are trying to find is 3 and the range is 1-10 then will it return like index 2 like as if the array is 1-10 or am I wrong...

Comment: Suppose predicate `f` was in fact `even` - that is, it returns true when the integer it is given is an even number, false otherwise.  Then on input you give it an array in which all the odd numbers precede (are at lower indexes) than the even numbers.  This function will find the index of the lowest even number.

Comment: It will return the smallest value `x` in the range `[1, 10]` for which `f(x) == true`. If `f(3) == true` while `f(2) == false`, then it'll return `3`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - but only if the array given is already properly partitioned!  Otherwise it will return ... what?

Comment: @davidbak `fstTrue` doesn't take an array on input. Your example doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @davidbak What is this "array" of which you speak? There's none in the code shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - quite right - I was mistaken.  however - it is necessary that the function `f` isn't arbitrary - it must partition the set of integers at some point.

Comment: see for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Comment: @davidbak  That's correct. In light of this fact, your `even` example doesn't make sense, as this predicate doesn't in fact partition a range of integers (except for trivial case of ranges of length 1, and half the ranges of length 2).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh I understand then ... How do I call the function? Like function<bool(int)> x =3; cout << fstTrue(x,1,10); This is probably wrong, im not so sure how to do this

Comment: Something like `int result = fstTrue([](int x) { return x >= 3;}, 1, 10);` Here, `result` would be `3` - the smallest value `x` in the range `[1, 10]` for which `x >= 3` is true.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ahh I see. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When do you think something like this would be useful?

Comment: I must admit I can't think of an example off the top of my head. Why don't you ask the author of this code what they wrote it for?

Comment: this is known as `discrete binary search` its a common usage of binary search mainly used in competitive programming. You can read more about it here: https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/binary-search

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hi, how would I input fstTrue if I changed the function like this:template<class T, class U> T fstTrue(T lo, T hi, U f) with the exact same code and implementation above. Thanks

Comment: `fstTrue(1, 10, [](int x) { return x >= 3;});` You just changed the order of parameters, so change the order of arguments to match.